# destroy and reload a tree graph using treant.js with ajax

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Treant.js](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/) library to draw some graphs and every thing is ok, but when I make ajax request to get another nodes and reload the graph, only one element displayed in the graph, note that the data is returned in correct format.

I searched about this issue, and I found this:

> To create the newly loaded data not enough to destroy tree .. it is
>   necessary to remove the data from the "store" for the tree in
>   TreeStore Then you must reset the counter id in method "make" in
>   JSONconfig

I'm using this configuration object:

```
var config = {  
    container: "#OrganiseChart8",  
    levelSeparation: 50,  
    siblingSeparation: 40,  
    nodeAlign: "BOTTOM",  
    connectors: {  
        type: "bCurve", // step  
        style: {  
            "stroke-width": 1,  
            "stroke": "#000",  
            "stroke-dasharray": "",   
            "arrow-end": "classic-wide-long",  
        }
    }
};
```

In short words, I want to do the following:

```
Tr = new Treant(tree_structure);  
Tr.destroy();  
how to remove the data from the store in TreeStore ?  
how to reset the counter id ?  
ajax call()  
Tr = new Treant(tree_structure);
```

the tree is not displayed !!

any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create the tree with

```
let testTree = new Treant(chartConfig, null, $);
```

Get Ajax data

```
    let ajaxNodeData = {
    text: {name: 'Fifteen'},
    HTMLid: 'fifteenID',
    position: 'center'
};
```

Add the new node

```
let nodeToAdd = $('#oneID');
testTree.tree.addNode(nodeToAdd.data('treenode'), ajaxNodeData);
```

If you want to destroy the whole tree and add the new one

```
testTree.destroy();
testTree = new Treant(simple_chart_config, null, $);
```

Comment: testTree.tree.addNode(nodeToAdd.data('treenode'), ajaxNodeData); what is 'treenode' in this specific line? please explain this

Answer (score 0):

Treant js api is not flexible.
I found a better alternative.

https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart

It support ondemand ajax loading of nodes.